# Structured Spark Streaming Throws OOM exception

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

My structured Spark Streaming Job fails with the following exception after running for more than 24 hrs.

```
Exception in thread "spark-listener-group-eventLog" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:1114)
        at java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(BigInteger.java:1098)
        at scala.math.BigInt$.apply(BigInt.scala:49)
        at scala.math.BigInt$.long2bigInt(BigInt.scala:101)
        at org.json4s.Implicits$class.long2jvalue(JsonDSL.scala:45)
        at org.json4s.JsonDSL$.long2jvalue(JsonDSL.scala:61)
```

Quick background:
My structured spark streaming job is to ingest events received as new files (parquet) into Solr collection. So, the sources are 8 different hive tables (8 different hdfs locations) receiving events and the sink is one solr collection.

Configuration:

```
Number Executors: 30
Executor Memory: 20 G
Driver memory: 20 G
cores - 5
```

Generated a hprof dump file and loaded into MAT to understand cause. The dump file looks like. This is a test environment and data stream TPS (transaction per minute) is very low and sometimes no transactions at all.

Any clue on what is causing this. Unfortunately, I'm unable to share the code snippet. Sorry about that.

[image]

[image]